# Generators of a subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: computational-algebra

So I have this subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z})$ which has $256$ elements. Is there a way in sage to get the list of its generators ? The "only" information I have on the group is the list of its elements.

If it is not implemented in Sage does anyone have a reference for an algorithm to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did it by using GAP. Look at this and I hope it works, unless, tell me to remove that.

```
gap> SL24:=SL(4,Integers mod 24);
gap> T:=GeneratorsOfGroup( SL24);;
gap> for i in [1..Size(T)] do Print(T[i],"\n"); od;

[ [ ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 23, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ),ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ) ], 
[ ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 1, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ) ], 
[ ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 1, 24 ) ], 
[ ZmodnZObj( 1, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ) ] ]

[ [ ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 23, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ) ], 
[ ZmodnZObj( 1, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ) ], 
[ ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 1, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ) ], 
[ ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 1, 24 ) ] ]

[ [ ZmodnZObj( 1, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 1, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ) ], 
[ ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 1, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ) ], 
[ ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 1, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ) ], 
[ ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 24 ), ZmodnZObj( 1, 24 ) ] ]
```

Comment: Hi Babak, thanks for answering. I'm not interested in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z})$ but in one of it's subgroups. On the other hand I didn't know gap and maybe the function GeneratorOfGroup will work. I'll try and let you know.

Comment: Nice output! +1

Comment: OK so after spending some time learning gap's syntax I managed to load my subgroup into it. Sadly the function GeneratorsOfGroup returns the $256$ elements of the group that I used to define it so it doesn't really help me. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @ZorbaleGrec: have you tried `MinimalGeneratingSet` or `SmallGeneratingSet` or `GeneratorsSmallest`? `GeneratorsOfGroup` returns the generators given to create the group, so if you generated it using all 256 elements, it will return just them.

Comment: Amazing it worked thanks ! In the end thank you very much to both of you Alexander and Babak. Should I now accept Babak's answer ?

Comment: It's interesting but the function doesn't always return the same set of generators so I guess they must use some kind of randomness in the algorithm they use. Do you know where I can find the code for that particular function, just to satisfy my curiosity ?

Comment: @ZorbaleGrec: to find the code, try e.g. `PageSource(ApplicableMethod(MinimalGeneratingSet,[G]));` where `G` is the subgroup you're dealing with.

Comment: It gave me the following error : Cannot locate source of kernel function GetterFunc(MinimalGeneratingSet).

Comment: @ZorbaleGrec: We have to wait till Alexander visit the case.

Comment: @ZorbaleGrec: "Cannot locate source of kernel function" in combination with `GetterFunc` means that in this case the value of the attribute `MinimalGeneratingSet` is already computed and stored in `G` (since `MinimalGeneratingSet` is an attribute). In this case, instead of computing it another time, GAP uses so called "getter" to get the stored value. To see the actual library code, create `G` once more and then call `PageSource(ApplicableMethod(...` **before** calling `MinimalGeneratingSet(G)`. In this case it is not yet computed, so `ApplicableMethod` should point to the code in question.